# Algorithm for extracting seasonal rainfall totals into a new vector

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have four vectors for each season containing the rainfall sum for each season in the period 1926 to 1999. I am trying to create a new vector `yearly.totals` which will extract elements from the seasonal vectors in such a way that it will contain the rainfall sums for each season ordered by year. It should read:

```
yearly.totals[1] = spring.totals[1]
yearly.totals[2] = summer.totals[1]
yearly.totals[3] = fall.totals[1]
yearly.totals[4] = winter.totals[1]
yearly.totals[5] = spring.totals[2]
yearly.totals[6] = summer.totals[2]
...
```

Note my 'year' begins in Spring. So far I have tried the following code:

```
year.length = length(spring.totals)+length(summer.totals)+length(fall.totals)+length(winter.totals)

yearly.totals = vector("numeric", year.length)

for(i in 1:length(yearly.totals)){
  if(i %in% seq(1,75,4)) {
    yearly.totals[i] = spring.totals[i]
  } else if(i %in% seq(2,75,4)) {
    yearly.totals[i] = summer.totals[i]
  } else if(i %in% seq(3,75,4)) {
    yearly.totals[i] = fall.totals[i]
  } else {
    yearly.totals[i] = winter.totals[i]
  }
}
```

This identifies which season each element belongs to using `seq()`. The problem lies in which element it extracts from the seasonal vectors. The first four elements are correct but after that it goes wrong. This is what happens:

```
yearly.totals[5] = spring.totals[5]
yearly.totals[6] = summer.totals[6]
...
```

I believe the solution might lie in changing the seasonal `i`th component within the for loop to something other than just `i`, but I can't figure it out. I tried `i - (i-1)`, which is fine for the first four elements but then just repeats.

```
for(i in 1:length(yearly.totals)){
  if(i %in% seq(1,75,4)) {
    yearly.totals[i] = spring.totals[i - (i-1)]
  } else if(i %in% seq(2,75,4)) {
    yearly.totals[i] = summer.totals[i - (i-1)]
  } else if(i %in% seq(3,75,4)) {
    yearly.totals[i] = fall.totals[i - (i-1)]
  } else {
    yearly.totals[i] = winter.totals[i - (i-1)]
  }
}

yearly.totals[5] = spring.totals[1]
yearly.totals[6] = summer.totals[1]
...
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rbind` your vectors into a matrix *r*ow-wise, and turn the matrix into a vector using `as.vector`, which will read the matrix column-wise:

```
> spring.totals <- 1:10
> summer.totals <- 11:20
> fall.totals <- 21:30
> winter.totals <- 31:40
> 
> as.vector(rbind(spring.totals,summer.totals,fall.totals,winter.totals))
 [1]  1 11 21 31  2 12 22 32  3 13 23 33  4 14 24 34  5 15 25 35  6 16 26 36  7
[26] 17 27 37  8 18 28 38  9 19 29 39 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Although I should say for anyone else reading that this only works for vectors of equal length. I had to slightly modify `winter.totals` to be of length 75 not 74.